# GROUP_CONCAT Question

Tags: mysql

So I am trying to do multiple `GROUP_CONCAT()`s in a query on the same column with if statements.
Even though the data is there, it is not giving me accurate info. I tried upping the `group_concat_max_len`, but I still get the same incorrect data.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT 
    field1,
    field2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(field3 = 2, field4, NULL)) list1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(field3 = 3, field4, NULL)) list2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(field3 = 4, field4, NULL)) list3
FROM table1
GROUP BY field5
```

The results in the `list1`, `list2` and `list3` are not accurate, though the data is. Am I hitting some constraint from doing it this way?

Comment: What _are_ the results in the lists? How long is each final string from `GROUP_CONCAT()`? What data do you have in your tables, what data is output by the above query, and what data do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT field1,field2,last1,list2,list3 FROM
(
    SELECT
        field1, 
        field2,
        field5,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(field3 = 2, field4, 'NULL')) list1, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(field3 = 3, field4, 'NULL')) list2, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(field3 = 4, field4, 'NULL')) list3 
    FROM
        table1 
    GROUP BY
        field1,field2,field5
) A;
```

I changed the SELECT list, changed the GROUP BY, changed NULL to 'NULL', put the whole query in a subquery, and pull out of the subquery everything except field5. Please see if this produces the desired result.

If you want this query to run fast, please add this index:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD INDEX (field1,field2,field5);
```